# django - best way for transfer money to users bank account

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am developing a django based application and want to transfer money to users bank account according to their earned points.

At the end of week I have a payback amount that should be send to users. How to deposit that amount to their bank account automatically at end of week.

Should I make transitions manually or there is any secure way to ?

Is it possible to transfer money from my bank account to another with script ? If not then how big companies like - adsense, facebook, amazon  transfers credits ???

Comment: I think a good start would be to look at the Python API for Stripe. It is used for payment processing. Here is a link: https://stripe.com/docs/api/python

Comment: @DougDresser thanks but I think strip is only for receiving payments

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can with `Payouts`. Look at https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#payouts
Basically all of your users will make a Stripe account, that way Stripe deals with all the sensitive information in a secure way, all you have to do is use the API.